# Text extraction with NSRegularExpression

Tags: ios, regex, iphone, text-extraction, nsregularexpression

Given a `NSString *test = @"...href="/functions?q=KEYWORD\x26amp...";`

How can I extract the word **KEYWORD** from the string using NSRegularExpression?
I have tried with the following NSRegularExpression on iOS SDK 4.2 but it is not able to find the text. Does the following code looks okay?

```
NSRegularExpression *testRegex = [NSRegularExpression regularExpressionWithPattern:@"(?<=href=\"\\/functions\\?q=).+?(?=\\x26amp])" options:0 error:nil];
NSRange result = [testRegex rangeOfFirstMatchInString:test options:0 range:NSMakeRange(0, [test length])];
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You have a stray "]" in your regex, right before the end, which is probably causing a problem. You also need to use four slashes to match a slash in the input string. (Double it to escape it in the C string, and then double again to escape it in the regex). I'd suggest two things. First, pass something in the error parameter and take a look at in it in the debugger. Second, I'm not a big fan of lookahead/lookbehind expressions. I think this style is more readable:

```
NSString *regexStr = @"href=\"\\/functions\\?=(.+?)\\\\x26amp";
NSError *error;
NSRegularExpression *testRegex = [NSRegularExpression regularExpressionWithPattern:regexStr options:0 error:&error];
if( testRegex == nil ) NSLog( @"Error making regex: %@", error );
NSTextCheckingResult *result = [testRegex firstMatchInString:test options:0 range:NSMakeRange(0, [test length])];
NSRange range = [result rangeAtIndex:1];
```

Comment: The stray "]" is my typo when posting my question. The key to solving the problem is the **four slashes to match a slash in the input string**. That is a lot of escaping! Thanks.